# How do I multiply and sum column data using awk and or sed?

Tags: sed, awk

I have several columns of data. I always have the same number of rows (say 5). In the 2nd column, I want to multipy the first value by 5, then the second value by 4, the third value by 3, etc. I then want to sum these values, and divide by the sum of the values in the second column. How would I do this in sed and/or awk?

Example:

```
4 5 7 1 2 3
5 1 2 3 1 2
4 2 3 6 1 2
3 4 1 6 3 3
2 3 1 2 1 6
```

Answer: `(5*5 + 4*1 + 3*2 + 2*4 + 1*3)/(5 + 1 + 2 + 4 + 3) = 3.067`

Comment: Is there some reason you want to do this with sed/awk?

Comment: I just wanted to automate the process without having to resort to a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace 6 with total (number of lines + 1) if needed:

```
awk '{mult+=$2*(6-NR); sum+=$2;} END {print mult/sum;}' yourfile.txt
```

Displays: `3.06667`

Comment: @markn No problem, you can check the tick (under the downvote arrow) if you consider this answer correct for you.

Answer (score 2):

If in case total number of lines are not known

```
$ cat file
4 5 7 1 2 3
5 1 2 3 1 2
4 2 3 6 1 2
3 4 1 6 3 3
2 3 1 2 1 6

$ awk 'FNR==NR{t = NR+1;next}{mult+=$2*(t-FNR);sum+=$2} 
       END{print mult/sum}' file{,}
3.06667
```

Explanation

`awk 'FNR == NR{t=NR+1;next}`

`FNR variable` --> Current line number in the current file

`NR  variable`-->The total number of lines seen so far

The condition `FNR == NR` can only be true while awk is reading the first file of argument

`t=NR+1` --> variable `t` holds line count `+1` extra since it's required in our current context

`next`--> Stops the processing of the current input record and proceeds with the next input record

`mult+=$2*(t-FNR)` --> variable `mult` holds some of `(5*(t-FNR) + ..... + 4*1 + 3*2 + 2*4 + 1*3)`

`sum+=$2` --> variable `sum` holds sum of column2

`END`--> An`END` rule is executed, once, after all the input has been read

`print mult/sum` --> Finally print mult/sum

`file{,}` --> you can also file `file file` but i used shortcut this bash trick you can say, try `echo file{,}` and `echo file{,,}` on your terminal.

Good Luck

Akshay.